# JavaScript Prompt Box Cancel Button?

Tags: javascript, prompt

I have a JavaScript function as follows:

```
function popup(username) {
var req = createAjaxObject();
var message = prompt("Message:","");
if(message != ""){
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            alert(req.responseText);
        }
    }
    req.open('POST','getmessage.php',true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    req.send("username=" + username +"&message="+message);
} else {
    alert("Please enter a message");
}
}
```

When the `Cancel` button is hit, the form is still processed through `getmessage.php`. Any way to have the `Cancel` button do nothing?

**EDIT:**

Here is the way this function is called:

```
                <?php
        mysqlLogin();
        $username = $_COOKIE['sqlusername'];
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE username!='$username'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0) {
            echo "<table class='usertable' align='center'>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                $username = $row['username'];
                echo "<tr><td><center>" . $row['username'] . "</center></td><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#' onClick=\"popup('$username');\">Send Message</a></td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "<center>No users found!</center>";
        }

    ?>
```

The `PHP` script its linked to:

```
<?php
$id = rand(1,1500);
$poster = $_POST['username'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$to = $_COOKIE['sqlusername'];

require('functions.php');
mysqlLogin();

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `messages` VALUES ('$id','$message','$to','$poster','')");
if($sql){
    echo "Message sent!";
} else {
    echo "Woops! Something went wrong.";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the case of `Cancel`, the prompt result is `null`, and `null != ''` (as per ECMA-262 Section 11.9.3).

So, add an extra explicit check for `null` inequality:

```
if(message != "" && message !== null) {
```

However, since the message is either some string or `null` and you only want to pass when it's a string with `length > 0`, you can also do:

```
if(message) {
```

This means: if message is truthy (i.e. not `null` or an empty string, amongst other falsy values), then enter the if clause.

Comment: No luck, it's still getting posted to the database.

Comment: Give 'if(message)' a try and see how you go

Comment: @Pimvdb the fiddle works, but my script doesn't
@cheesus `if(message)` doesn't work.

Comment: @Jason: If both of these suggestions don't work and the fiddle does work, then there must be something else not correct.

Comment: @pimvdb check the recent edit, maybe you guys can spot another error.

Comment: Problem solved, I was editing the wrong script :( stupid me! But yes, `if(message)` worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Safari by any chance?  I have found that Safari seems to be returning empty string instead of null when the user clicks Cancel.

See here: [Safari 5.1 prompt() function and cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351124/safari-5-1-prompt-function-and-cancel).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, my suggested comment does work

```
var message = prompt("Message:","");
if(message){
    alert("Not working!");
} else {
    alert("Working!");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hCqCs/)

Comment: I know, but for some reason my script is passing the `null` value in to the php script.

Answer (score 1):

```
var message = prompt("Message:","");
if(message){
    alert("Message accepted, now i can process my php or script and blablabla!");
} else {
    alert("Cancel Press or Empty Message, do nothing!");
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation to the code? Posting only the code may detract from an answers usefulness.

Comment: I'm sorry....i'am new and i still have problems with your language....but i want to help...sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = prompt('type any...', '');
if(message+'.' == 'null.')
{
    alert("you've canceled");
}
else
{
    alert("type ok");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                $.messager.prompt('Save To File', 'FileName:', function(e){
                    if (e.response!='undefined'){
                        if (r!="")
                        {   
                          alert('Your FileName is:' + r);   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          $.messager.alert('Err...','FileName cannot empty!!!');
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Apologies for being thick but how does this answer the question?