# Safari 5.1.4 showModalDialog returning undefined

Tags: javascript, safari

We're using the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7354041/634419) to [Safari 5.1 prompt() function and cancel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351124/safari-5-1-prompt-function-and-cancel) as a replacement for `prompt` in Safari 5.1, to work around the bug in that browser where the "Cancel" button returns the empty string rather than `null`.

Now we're suddenly having trouble with `showModalDialog` often (but not always) returning undefined instead of the value assigned to the popup's `returnValue` property. Note this is *not* due to cross-domain issues and is *not* due to form submission or other page reloads in the popup. While this may be unrelated, the problem does not occur on a machine still running Snow Leopard rather than Lion. The problem also does not occur in Firefox, Chromium, or IE8. A test page is available at http://www.thesaabsite.com/js/safari-5.1-bugfix-test.html.

Is something wrong with what we're doing, or is it a bug in Safari?

Comment: We've started seeing this problem on Safari for Windows, too.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Chrome. Although the cause is probably not the same, the workaround given in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213530/javascript-showmodaldialog-not-returning-value-in-chrome) may help you, at least until you find the real solution.