# How to close showModalDialog in FireFox,Chrome in javascript

Tags: javascript, alert, showmodaldialog

```
var userChoice = showModalDialog("../Iframe.aspx?FormName=sample.aspx", window,     "dialogTop:300px;dialogLeft:350px;dialogHeight:182px;dialogWidth:370px;help:no;scroll:no;status:no;");        
alert(userChoice); /* here iam not able to get 'Y' */      
if (userChoice == 'Y')       
  return true; else return false;     

 Below is the Sample aspx page:  

  input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="choice('Y')"    

function userChoice(option)     
{       
 window.returnValue = option;    
 alert(window.returnValue);  /* here iam getting 'Y' */
 parent.close(); // I have tried with self.close() also  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't close `parent.window` from modal dialog. Use `window.close()` or `top.close()` to close the modal.

There was a bug with `returnValue` within Chrome, it seems it's not fixed yet, plese try these:

[showModalDialaog not returning value in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213530/1169519)

[chromium/issues/detail?id=42939](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42939)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried with window.close() --> it is not closing in mozilla and top.close() --> it is closing in mozilla but the value is returning null after closed instead of 'Y'

Comment: @chinna373 There should be no problems with Firefox, for Chrome, please follow the links I've provided in my answer.

Comment: I have tried in mozilla, its not working and googled. please check this link also "dotnetspider.com/forum/305804-How-close-showModalDialog-FireFox-Chrome.aspx"

Comment: @chinna373 Hmm... I can't reproduce this issue in FF 17.0.1. Can you save an example code in http://www.jsfiddle.net ? Also this may have something to do with `.aspx`, have you tried to load a regular `.html` page into your modal dialog?

Comment: I had the same issue with closing the showModalDialog in FF. `top.close()` did work for me(IE,Chrome as well). Thanks a lot @Teemu