# workaround of Chrome 37+ modal dialog returnValue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I have a parent caller page and a modal page, when the modal page is closed, the caller page gets a returnValue from the popup modal page. Even older version Chrome's `showModalDialog()` always returns undefined, there are many workarounds  [[javascript - showModalDialog not returning value in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10213530/1299675]).

But now window.showModalDialog() in Chrome37+ is deprecated by design [http://blog.chromium.org/2014/07/disabling-showmodaldialog.html], those workarounds to get returnValue of a popup window do not work anymore.

Than I tried `window.open()`, but window.open act quite differently from `showModalDialog`, and its not easy to get the correct returnValue (since `window.open()` is asynchronous).

So is there a perfect way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Jquery Modal Dialog Framework](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

**JQuery Modal Dialog Example**

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
    close: function( event, ui ) {
        alert('dialog closed');
        return;
    }
});
```

Or the [Fancybox Framework](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/)

**Fancybox Example**

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterClose : function() {
        alert('dialog closed');
        return;
    }
});
```

Both frameworks provide callback handlers so that you can store or pass values to other functions...