# cancelling alert poppup in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider this code:

```
function reason(id) {
    var reason = prompt("State reason");
    while (!reason.trim()) {
        reason = prompt("Please enter text");
    }
    document.getElementById(id).value = reason;
    return true;
}
```

It works perfectly fine, but when I want to get rid of the poppup by pressing escape for example, the function returns true because the form executes. What should I do to make it do nothing if I close/cancel the poppup?

Comment: return false; should work for both the cases

Comment: `return reason;` probably works - prompt returns null on cancel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript prompt() - cancel button to terminate the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864582/javascript-prompt-cancel-button-to-terminate-the-function)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ the asker of the question you linked specifically said he clicked the cancel button to cancel the alert, I didn't click any buttons, I just pressed escape which should get rid of the alert.

Comment: @morbidCode clicking `Cancel` is equivalent to pressing `Esc` for `prompt` and `confirm` dialogs.

Comment: @morbidCode: True, but pressing escape effectively is invoking the "Cancel" action. Also, note that Safari also returns an empty string on Cancel -- it does not differentiate between cancelling and entering an empty string (via [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)), so you could get stuck in an infinite prompt loop.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: *"Also, note that Safari also returns an empty string on Cancel"* Gak. If MDN is really right about that, it's Yet Another Reason not to use `prompt` (not that we were short of them).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: [Some more discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351124/safari-5-1-prompt-function-and-cancel) on the Safari issue. "Gak" indeed!

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ: Doesn't do that on my iPhone, I get `null`: http://jsbin.com/pukunodatu Re that link: Safari 5.1 is ***ancient***.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Well, that's good to know. Admittedly as someone who hasn't used a Mac/iOS in many years I'm happy I probably don't have to remember another browser quirk. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... the function returns true because the form executes. What should I do to make it do nothing if I close/cancel the poppup?

It depends entirely on how you call your `reason` function, but if you want `reason` to return `false` when `prompt` is cancelled, then:

```
function reason(id) {
    var reason = prompt("State reason");
    while (reason !== null && !reason.trim()) {  // *** Changed
        reason = prompt("Please enter text");
    }
    if (reason === null) {                       // *** Added
        return false;                            // *** Added
    }                                            // *** Added
    document.getElementById(id).value = reason;
    return true;
}
```

`prompt` returns `null` when you cancel it.

But again, it's up to what calls `reason` to do something appropriate with the `true` or `false`.

---

Side note: You **can** call your function and a variable inside it by the same name, but it's not a great idea. If it's a habit, you'll end up making writing recursive functions quite difficult...

Comment: @NG.: What I get for stopping reading at the first `prompt`. :-) Thanks, fixed now.