# JavaScript Cancel on Prompt

Tags: javascript, prompt, confirm

Hi I was wondering what the difference between the prompt() method and confirm() methods are?

and also: I was wondering how to modify the following code, so that when the user cancels the prompt box, a block of code is executed.

```
var userInput = prompt("Write your name","");
if(prompt == //user cancels//){
code to be executed;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: should be confirm('message here');

Comment: This question is already answered here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6962718/javascript-prompt-box-cancel-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user cancels [prompt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp), then it returns null.
Since `null` is **falsy**, you can simply check for `!prompt`:

```
var result = prompt("ask user something");
if (!result) {

};
```

However, in your case, it looks like you want [`confirm`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp) function.
The difference is that prompt is a text input dialog, which returns inputed string or `null`.
Confirm is Yes / No dialog, which returns `true` or `false`.

```js
var result = confirm('Click Yes or No!');

// Both approaches are working, choose the one you like:
if (result) console.log('Yes (result)');
if (result === true) console.log('Yes (result === true)');

// Both approaches are working, choose the one you like:
if (!result) console.log('No (!result)');
if (result === false) console.log('No (result === false)');
```

Answer (score 1):

On `Cancel` `null` is returned

```
 var a = prompt("ask user something", "")
    if (a === null) {
      alert(' Cancel pressed')
    }
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vuj6dyyc/1/)